# Convert a shapefile to geographic coordinates

Tags: python, geospatial, shapefile, matplotlib-basemap, ogr2ogr

Very new to `geospatial` data - I'm currently working to get a set of postcodes labelled within their correct geographical region, as defined by NUTS1. I figured the best way of doing this would be to:

1. Get the coordinates of the NUTS1 regions;
2. Convert these into a polygon;
3. Get the coordinates of a postcode and see which polygon it sits inside

However - I've hit a barrier with step (1) - the data from the ONS in respect of the NUTS regions isn't in longitude / latitude format from what I gather (see source and error below). From similar questions, I gather `ogr2ogr` is the way to convert this - so I've downloaded `OSGeo4W` which has `ogr2ogr`, however I'm not entirely what I should be running in my `OSGeo4W` power shell to make the appropriate conversions.

I've also consulted the below cheat sheet, still no luck however.

I gather geopandas has a very simple answer to my problem - however, after 2 days of attempting to install this package, I still haven't had any luck so I'm stepping back from that avenue temporarily (on a separate note, if any one has had any luck installing geopandas with python 3.7, do point me in the right direction. I've attempted the conda install and downloading all whl files individually, neither seemed to work).

I wondered if someone might be able to spell out for a newbie the precise command that I need to be running to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Data source: http://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/datasets/nuts-level-1-january-2018-full-extent-boundaries-in-the-united-kingdom/data

> Error: ValueError: shapefile must have lat/lon vertices

It looks like this one has vertices
in map projection coordinates. You can convert the shapefile to geographic
coordinates using the `shpproj` utility from the `shapelib` tools
(http://shapelib.maptools.org/shapelib-tools.html)

Cheat sheet: http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet

Comment: I formated  your code sample by using `Numbered List` instead of `(1)` and formated `tag` words using backticks. [Please see the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for more information on formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to transform your original data to the ubiquitous [WGS84](https://epsg.io/4326) Coordinate Reference System using the `-t_srs` option for the `ogr2ogr` cli program. Read more about all the current options for `ogr2ogr` [here](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).

`ogr2ogr boundaries.shp NUTS_Level_1_January_2018_Full_Extent_Boundaries_in_the_United_Kingdom.shp -t_srs epsg:4326`

The dataset is already in 'ST_Polygon' form so step 2 is moot.

I will leave it as an exercise for you to figure out step 3 on your own; hint: you can do spatial joins with ogr2ogr using `-sql -dialect sqlite`.